# cells that start w same character input w/o losing character

Tags: excel

I've been trying to figure if there's a way in Excel (I have 2013) to create cells that all start with the same character, but I can still input without losing said character. For example: I have a large list of part numbers, all of which start with "R-". What I would like to accomplish is that I have a column of cells already starting with "R-" that my data entry folk can just add numbers to. R-1234, R-57642, etc.

Comment: You can prepopulate with R-, but they would have to double click to get into edit mode before adding the digits.  Or you could have them enter the digits in empty cells in column A, and column B would create the full string of R-1234 which would then be used for whatever purpose you have

Answer (score 0):

This is for column **A**.

Click on the column and apply the custom format:

```
 "R-"General
```

[image]

as value are typed in column **A**, the **P-** will be pre-appended.

This is format only..............a macro can do this "for real":

**EDIT#1:**

This is also for column **A**.  Do **not** apply the custom format listed above; instead place the following worksheet event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, rINT As Range, r As Range

    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set rINT = Intersect(A, Target)
    If rINT Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In rINT
            v = r.Value
            If v <> "" Then
                If Left(v, 2) <> "R-" Then
                    r.Value = "R-" & v
                End If
            End If
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It will monitor changes to column **A** and automatically pre-append the **"R-"**